# Dockerize Spring Boot Java app with Kafka, Zookeeper, and MongoDB

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, dockerfile

I am a beginner to Docker and web applications in general. I have to Dockerize a large Spring Boot Java app that uses Kafka, Zookeeper, and MongoDB. It also uses the Gradle build tool. What would be the best approach to Dockerize this app? Should I Dockerize it in one image, or a separate image for each component?

Also, how do I incorporate the Gradle build tool in the Dockerfile?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the "large Java app" currently deploy or ensure the existance and correct configuration of the collaterals Kafka, Zookeeper, and MongoDB? This is an important hint on what route you mght follow into container land. What is your understanding of "incorporate Gradle build tool in Dockerfile", do you mean - seeing the Dockerfile as kind of a Makefile - to be given some recipes as which syntax element for a Dockerfile the relevant "calls" should be written into the file? Please provide some more details. Thanks.

Comment: So the app runs using Spring Boot. There is an external configuration file called "application.properties" that contains the configurations for Kafka, Zookeeper, and MongoDB. It gets passed in through command line as in:

 `sudo -u root java -Dspring.config.location="location of config file" -jar javaApp.jar`

Regarding the incorporation of Gradle into the Dockerfile, I now think it would be best to decouple Gradle and Docker initially by letting Gradle build the JAR file first and then letting Docker work with that (as discussed below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Gradle, there is a [docker-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin), which you can use to dockerize your Java applications.

Putting multiple applications in one Docker build is not the way Docker is intended to be used. There are already Docker images available for tools like Kafka, ZooKeeper and MongoDB. You just use them as a separate container and link them to your dockerized/ non-dockerized Java application.

> Also, how do I incorporate the Gradle build tool in the Dockerfile?

You actually will incorporate Docker Build in Gradle build file. Not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, that is an option, in which you need two steps. You can create a Dockerfile that builds your images based on the jar file created by the Gradle. Then you can call `docker build` on this Dockerfile. Instead, if you use the docker-gradle-plugin, you can combine both steps together. It's up to you how you want to do it.

Comment: What if I first let Gradle build the whole app and make the JAR file? I could then just add the JAR file into the Dockerfile and execute it as follows:

`FROM java:7`
`ADD /javaApp/build/libs/javaApp.jar javaApp.jar`
`ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","javaApp.jar"`

Do you think that would be a viable approach?
After that, I would have to pull and run the images for Kafka, Zookeeper, and MongoDB and then link them to my Dockerized javaApp.

Comment: As I said above it's a viable option. But you need some extra steps. One correction though, you don't need the statement `ADD /javaApp/build/libs/javaApp.jar javaApp.jar`. Instead, you should make your javaApp available either in the main or sub directories of directory where your Dockerfile is. Docker itself will copy that jar into the image. Docker may not be able to access any files out side of its context directory. I tried and got error. And, yeah, after that you just do what you said for the other images, "pull and run".

Comment: Aah yes I see. So one thing that may be an issue is that my Java app depends on Kafka, Zookeeper, and MongoDB. So wouldn't I FIRST need to spin up the Kafka, Zookeeper, and MongoDB containers? Then I could build my Java app and Dockerize it.

Also, what are the main concepts I should learn about before linking the containers together? I was thinking of learning about ports for a start? Sorry, I'm a true beginner to all of this so it's all quite foreign to me.

Comment: You don't need the other containers running to build the image. However, you will need them running before you run your Java App's images. I meant start the container. Easier way is to create a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) file and link other containers to your Java app. Don't worry about being beginner. We all been there.